# What is a standard textbook about editing writing by non-native speakers?

Tags: discussion, editing

What is a textbook that teaches editors and proofreaders good practice, methods, techniques and resources for editing the advanced writing of non-native speakers, for example academic writing or professional publishing?

Comment: What differences do you see in how editing should be done for non-native speakers vs native? Do you mean that an editor should let certain things go because they know the writer is a non-native speaker that they otherwise wouldn’t?

Comment: [Here](https://21centurytext.wordpress.com/editing-non-native-english/) is one although it isn't an actual book. It does contain plenty of references.

Comment: Or (following @Jim) do you want a list of common mistakes made by foreigners so that these mistakes are easier to find?

Comment: I doubt there is such a book, or can be. What kinds of audience? More important, what kind of foreigners? They don't all make the same kinds of mistake, you know. And it's hard to tell a local technical usage from a foreign mistake, when dealing with technical literature.